# How can I install multiprocessing env framework for Anaconda?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, python-import

I downloaded a Jupiter notebook and I was running the code blocks and I got an error from common.multiprocessing_env import SubprocVecEnv.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multiprocessing_env'
```

I searched the web for this, and the command `conda install -c auto multiprocessing` does not work. What is the work around for this?

Apparently, the project was abandoned so its not compatible with Python 3. I was going to ask the author of this notebook but I saw a couple age-old unanswered questions so I am probably not going to get a quick reply back.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to insert file `multiprocessing_env.py` in your working directory. Then you might type
`from multiprocessing_env import SubprocVecEnv`.

The file `multiprocessing_env.py` you might find here - https://github.com/higgsfield/RL-Adventure-2/tree/master/common